# Matching to find a line and then extracting certain elements from the line w regex using perl

Tags: regex, perl, web-scraping

I am writing a webscraper in perl. I am having troubles trying to extract what I want from the data that is returned in the get("url"); function. I want find a particular line with a regex and then use another regex to match and store the matches in an array. If someone could give me an example that would be super helpful.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::Simple;

$regex  = m/Prerequisite:.[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}/g;
$regex2 = m/[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}/g;

$content = $ARGV[0];
#print $content;
$urlundergrad = "http://www.handbook.unsw.edu.au/undergraduate/courses/2014/$content.html";
$urlpostgrad  = "http://www.handbook.unsw.edu.au/postgraduate/courses/2014/$content.html";

if ( @ARGV = 1 ) {
    $pageU = get("$urlundergrad") or die "unable to retrieve";
    #$pageP = get("$urlPostgrad") or die "unable to retrieve";

    foreach $line ( split( "\n", $pageU ) ) {
        if ( $line =~ $regex ) {
            push( @courses, $line );
        }
    }

    print @courses;
    print "\n";

} else {
    print "usage: prereq.pl <UNSW course>";
}
```

Comment: Have you been to http://perldoc.perl.org and read through the regex documentation there?

Comment: Have a look at [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/release/WWW-Mechanize). There you will also find examples.

Comment: The data returned by `get("url")` is HTML, which you should not attempt to parse with regex. Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1382251 in order to understand why, and keep in mind that the only person in the world that can parse HTML with regex is most likely Chuck Norris (though I admit I wasn't the first one to realize that).

Comment: thanks for the help. Where is Chuck Norris when you need him.

Comment: @user18018: Last time I heard he was making use of Chuck Norris jokes as part of the National Rifle Association campaign for defending the Second Amendment and promoting gun laws in the United States...

Comment: You should also turn on warnings and strict behaviour by adding `use strict; use warnings;` under the first line of your program. It is good programming practice and will prevent lots of problems down the road!

Comment: Funny, than everybody talking here about "parsing" and the op want simple "matching"... While I agree, than the easiest way would be using tools like `Mojo::Dom` or `Web::Scrape` but matching some text **isn't the same as parsing HTML**.

Comment: I agree with @jm666.  Regex is (potentially) fine here.

Comment: So you're already pushing the prerequisite lines into the @courses array. What do you want to do with them after you're done matching them?

Comment: Your definition of $regex and $regex2 should use qr// instead of m//.  Will there be more than one prerequisite per line matched?

Answer (score 0):

you are not using regular expressions the right way. either you can use the 'qr' operator like this:

```
$regex = qr/Prerequisite:.[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}/;
.
.
.
if ( $line =~ $regex ) {
```

please note that you can not use 'g' modifier with qr. also I don't see any reason to do so in your case. read more about qr [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

The other way I can think of is to use a variable to store your regular expression is this:

```
$regex = q/Prerequisite:.[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}/;
.
.
.
if ( $line =~ m/$regex/g ) {
```

also, please note you have a bug in line 13. you probably meant:

```
if ( @ARGV == 1 ) {
```